# Undefined key _paginator in MatTableDataSouce :

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

In the below-attached image, as you can see _paginator key-value pair is Undefined in the MatTableDataSouce object. Because of this, the paginator is not working.

[image]

Comment: is this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010053/mat-paginator-of-mat-tabledoesnt-work-with-api-data/64010762#64010762

Answer (score 0):

This issue was getting caused because,

@ViewChild('paginator', { **static: true** }) paginator: MatPaginator

static was true, by making static false the paginator started to work as expected.

@ViewChild('paginator', { **static: false** }) paginator: MatPaginator