# Pagination does not work after I perform an operation on table like add/edit/delete a row (Angular 10)

Tags: angular, pagination, angular10, mat-table, mat-pagination

I am paginating my table using mat-paginator. The pagination works fine when the first time the page is loaded. However if I perform an CRUD operation then the pagination does not work. All of the rows are displayed in the same page. I think its because I am using pagination inside *ngIf to show result table on condition.  I researched on google and tried some solution like using [hidden], set static to false in @viewchild pagination field. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 
 public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IUser>();
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

 constructor(
 ){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IUser>(this.users);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

}
```

users.component.html

```
<div class="users-container" *ngIf="UsersResults">
  <mat-card fxLayout="column" @fade class="users-card mat-elevation-z6">
    <div fxFlex="10" fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
       <h1 class="heading">Users</h1>

       <button mat-raised-button class="user-button" (click)="showCreateUserView()">Create User</button>
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="80">
      <span fxFlex="3"></span>
      <div fxFlex="100">
        <table class="result-table" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortStart="desc">
           <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
             <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header id="username">Username</th>
             <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
               <button mat-button(click)="showEditUserView(element)" [disableRipple]="true" matToolTip="click to edit user">{{element.username}}</button>
             </td>
           </ng-container>

           <ng-container matColumnDef="admin">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef id="status">Status</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                       
              </td>
           </ng-container>

           <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
           <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>

        <mat-paginator #paginator
                       [pageIndex]="0"
                       [pageSize]="7"
                       [pageSizeOptions]="[15, 30]">
        </mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: does this help - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Looks like this issue is caused by Angular where view child does not catch elements with *ngIf in ngAfterViewInit so this workaround solution worked for me. Github link for the similar issue provided below:

If there is better solution for this, please feel free to post it here.

Remove the code:

```
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

from ngAfterViewInit and add the following code:

```
    private paginator: MatPaginator;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
```

http://www.github.com/angular/components/issues/10205

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010053/mat-paginator-of-mat-tabledoesnt-work-with-api-data/64010762#64010762

Comment: Hi @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, thanks if it was your solution! It helped me solve the problem. However, I did provide the reference for Github issue where I found this solution. And it seems like it was not you (at least not this name) who solved it.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I just realized that you have posted the comment on my question and I know what you are talking about.

But I found the GitHub issue before you posted it here and if you see my Answer timestamp, you will find that. I did not see your comment with link until now but Thanks a lot..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, just in case you are wondering, I did not downvote. is nice to know you found a solution