# Not able to sort data correspoing to column in header in Angular material Table

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, angular-material-15, angular-material-11

[clinical history data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAoEp.png)
[the output i m getting that not by order asc desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN9Gc.png)

I'm trying to sort the data that I have in the table, and I use the MatTableModule module with the required other modules.

but I did research but didn't get a satisfactory answer.

**this is my TS file**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EmrService } from '../../services/emr.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { patient } from '../../interface/patient';
import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';

export interface UserData {
  PatientId: any;
  ClinicalEventDate: any;
  clinicalEventType: any;
  reportType: any;
  clinicalDetails: any;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-clinic-history',
  templateUrl: './clinic-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clinic-history.component.css'],
})

export class ClinicHistoryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ClinicalEventDate', 'clinicalEventType', 'reportType', 'clinicalDetails'];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('input') input!: ElementRef;
  IsLoading: boolean = true;
  PatientData!: patient;
  esteblishment_id: any;
  data!: UserData[] | undefined;

  visitTypeMap: { [key: number]: string } = {
    1: 'In Patient',
    2: 'Out Patient',
    3: 'Emergency',
    4: 'Day Care',
  };
  constructor(private router: Router, public emrservice: EmrService, private toaster: ToastrService, private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('nginit');
    let userData: any = localStorage.getItem('userdata');
    userData = JSON.parse(userData);
    if (userData?.esteblishment_user_map_id) {
      this.esteblishment_id = userData.esteblishment_user_map_id;
      this.emrservice.patientData$.subscribe((res: patient | null) => {
        if (res) {
          this.PatientData = res;
          let patientId = this.PatientData.patient_id;
          if (patientId) {
            // this.cdr.detectChanges();
            this.getClinicalHistory(patientId);
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngafter')
  }

  getClinicalHistory(patientId: any) {
    this.IsLoading = true;
    this.emrservice.viewPastHistory(this.esteblishment_id, patientId).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        console.log('view past clinical history data', res);
        if (res.status) {
          this.data = res.data;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          // this.data = undefined;
          // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(undefined);
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.IsLoading = false;
          }, 500);
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.IsLoading = false;
            this.data = undefined;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(undefined);
            this.toaster.warning("", "No records found");
          }, 500);
        }
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.data = undefined;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(undefined);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.IsLoading = false;
        }, 500);
        this.toaster.error("", "Something went wrong");
      }
    })
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource!.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource!.paginator) {
      this.dataSource!.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  onDiagnostic(value: any) {
    if (value == 'Diagnostic Report') {
      this.router.navigate(['doctor/emr/patient/diagnostic-report'])
    } else if (value == 'Op Consultation') {
      this.router.navigate(['doctor/emr/patient/op-consultation'])

    } else if (value == 'Discharge Summary') {
      this.router.navigate(['doctor/emr/patient/discharge-summary'])

    } else if (value == 'Record Prescription') {
      this.router.navigate(['doctor/emr/patient/record-prescription'])

    }
  }

  onMatSortChange(s: any) {
    console.log("matsorchanging")
  }

  Error() {
    return `❌ Not Found ${this.input.nativeElement.value}`
  }
}
```

**this is my html file**

```
<div class="header">View Past Clinical History recorded in this facility</div>
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="w-75 mb-2">
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. Aug 18 2023" #input />
  <span matPrefix><mat-icon class="search-icon">search</mat-icon>&nbsp;</span>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8 overflow-auto">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="w-100" matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear
    matSortDirection="desc">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ClinicalEventDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        Clinical Event Date
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="wrap">
        {{ this.emrservice.convertTowDDDMMYYYYTime(row.created_at) }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="clinicalEventType">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Clinical Event Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="wrap">
        {{ visitTypeMap[row.visit_type] }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="reportType">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Record Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="wrap">{{ row.type }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="clinicalDetails">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Clinical Details</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="wrap">
        <a class="btn-sm link-primary pointer" (click)="onDiagnostic(row.type)">Click Here</a>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

    <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td class="mat-cell" colspan="7" class="wrap text-center">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center py-2">
          {{ this.data ? Error() : "❌ Data not available" }}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator class="w-100" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**this is my module file where this component is registered**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { PatientRoutingModule } from './patient-routing.module';
import { PatientComponent } from './patient.component';
import { ClinicHistoryComponent } from './clinic-history/clinic-history.component';
import { DiagnosticReportComponent } from './diagnostic-report/diagnostic-report.component';
import { OpConsultationComponent } from './op-consultation/op-consultation.component';
import { DischargeSummaryComponent } from './discharge-summary/discharge-summary.component';
import { RecordPrescriptionComponent } from './record-prescription/record-prescription.component';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { TextFieldModule } from '@angular/cdk/text-field';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { LoaderForEmrModule } from '../loader-for-emr/loader-for-emr.module';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { PdfViewerComponent } from './pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component';
import { SafePipe } from 'src/app/safe.pipe';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PatientComponent,
    ClinicHistoryComponent,
    DiagnosticReportComponent,
    OpConsultationComponent,
    DischargeSummaryComponent,
    RecordPrescriptionComponent,
    PdfViewerComponent,
    SafePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    PatientRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    TextFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    LoaderForEmrModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class PatientModule { }
```

I have to sort the data, correspoding to column

Comment: it's like this [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010053/mat-paginator-of-mat-tabledoesnt-work-with-api-data/64010762#64010762+ with mat-paginator). But remember: if you use `static:true` in a ViewChildren, your component can **not** be under a *ngIf -should be visible always- and the matSort only is visible when the table is visible.

Comment: i tried as you say, buts its not work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you have a "loading" and, when the loading is visible, the table not.

This is the reason Angular can not "reach" the mat-sort. Futhermore if you write `static:true}` Angular only "search" the mat-sort at very stage on your component, if not present never check if it come to scene

```
getClinicalHistory(patientId: any) {
    this.IsLoading = true;
    this.emrservice.viewPastHistory(this.esteblishment_id, patientId).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        console.log('view past clinical history data', res);
        this.IsLoading = false; //<--first isLoading=false
        //then in a setTimeout without any seconds 
        setTimeout(()=>{
           if (res.status) {
                this.data = res.data;
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
           } else {
             this.data = undefined;
             this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(undefined);
             this.toaster.warning("", "No records found");
           }
         })
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.data = undefined;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(undefined);
        this.toaster.error("", "Something went wrong");
      }
    })
  }
```

**Update** About your problem:

I just see what can happens. When you use MatSort, by defect,you only can sort by the "property" you defined in the `reportType`, e.g. when you write

```
<!--see that you write matColumnDef--->
<ng-container matColumnDef="ClinicalEventDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        Clinical Event Date
      </th>
      ...
</ng-container>
```

You sort only if your elements have a property: `ClinicalEventDate`

I imagine should be

```
<!--see that the matColumnDef is create_at-->
<ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        Clinical Event Date
      </th>
      ...
</ng-container>
```

And you need change `displayedColumns` array

It's also posible indicate in mat-sort-header any "property", so, e.g.

```
<!--see that you write matColumnDef--->
<ng-container matColumnDef="ClinicalEventDate">
      <!--but you order by another "property"-->
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="created_at">
        Clinical Event Date
      </th>
      ...
</ng-container>
```

This allow, e.g. when we have a date, create a new property in the way yyyyMMdd and show one property but order by this "auxiliar property". See for inspiration, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968027/angular-material-table-sorting-list-of-ips/64968344#64968344) that create an auxiliar property 'normalized' to sort the IPs.

Comment: I tried as you say, but it works for me, Is there anything wrong with IsLoading then I also commented this.IsLoading. but even its not works

Comment: @ErMapsh, I just discovered what can happens: it's wrong defined the mat-sort and the matColumnDef. I update my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot @Eliseo, issue is resolved now i tried  mat-sort-header="created_at". that's work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep -  **@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;**
Also remove sort from component which you import.
IF any error kindly ping

Comment: I'm using strict mode thats why I used ! –

Comment: Are you getting data in grid? cause you have used next() for that you need to create a inner scopeThis which can access outer 'this'.
Else create let scopeThis = this; inside getClinicalHistory() and then
scopeThis.dataSource.sort = scopeThis.sort;
also you use @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

Comment: I just edit the question and added an image that helps u to understand how i m getting the data

Comment: we ur using a strict mode that does not allow us, to declare var without initialize In that  case  we declared a var without declaration in angular using explementary symbol